# How can one disable future dates from the current date and also disable dates 1 month before the current date using Blazor?

Tags: forms, date, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using Blazor date input how can you disable future dates from the current date and also disable dates 1 month or more before the current date? But display the current date when page loads.

I'm using Blazor-Server-Side.

So far I have the razor page set like this:

```
<InputDate @bind-Value="viewmodel.Date" class="form-control" id="date"></InputDate> 
<label> The date </label>
<ValidationMessage For="() => viewmodel.Date" />
```

And the model like this:

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select the date")]        
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

I have tried 'max' attribute in the input tag to leave an end date but it did not work. I could not find a method to do this. Please let me know how I can solve this in Balzor or if there are other ways to achieve the same results? I would prefer if no jquery was used.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy to do it in the markup, you can use min and max

```html
<input type="date" min="2021-11-01" max="2022-01-31"/>
```

This example restricts to dates between 1st November 2021 and 31st Jan 2022 - the format yyyy-MM-dd is important in min/max.

You can use variables for the dates in Blazor, but make sure to format them using yyyy-MM-dd.

```html
<InputDate @bind-Value="viewmodel.Date" 
    class="form-control" 
    id="date" 
    min=@DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") 
    max=@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd")  
    />
```

[Blazor Repl - Working Sample](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cbvmHkFV079uEsBV43)

Comment: I have already tried the 'max' attribute in the input tag but as you say it has restrictions which is not what I'm looking for.  By having min and max values I would have to change these everyday - which is not ideal. Unless there is a method to +1 to the min and max values.

Comment: You would just use variables as I said in my last sentence...

Comment: Could you show me a full example? It may be easier.

Comment: Sure, I have edited the answer and provided a sample